# Listen for key press in .NET console app

Tags: c#, console-application

How can I continue to run my console application until a key press (like <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed?)

I'm assuming its wrapped around a while loop. I don't like `ReadKey` as it blocks operation and asks for a key, rather than just continue and listen for the key press.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 400, accepted):

Use [`Console.KeyAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) so that you only call `ReadKey` when you know it won't block:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to stop");
do {
    while (! Console.KeyAvailable) {
        // Do something
   }       
} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Comment: but if you do this instead of readLine() you lose the awesome feature of having history recall by pressing "up" key.

Comment: @v.oddou After the last line, simply add your `Console.ReadLine()` and you're set, no?

Comment: Won't this loop consume a lot of CPU/RAM? If not, how so?

Answer (score 91):

You can change your approach slightly - use `Console.ReadKey()` to stop your app, but do your work in a background thread:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myWorker = new MyWorker();
    myWorker.DoStuff();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

In the `myWorker.DoStuff()` function you would then invoke another function on a background thread (using `Action<>()` or `Func<>()` is an easy way to do it), then immediately return.

Answer (score 80):

The shortest way:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to stop");

while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape))
{
    // do something
}
```

`Console.ReadKey()` is a blocking function, it stops the execution of the program and waits for a key press, but thanks to checking `Console.KeyAvailable` first, the `while` loop is not blocked, but running until the <kbd>Esc</kbd> is pressed.

Answer (score 24):

From the video curse Building .NET Console Applications in C# by Jason Roberts at http://www.pluralsight.com

We could do following to have multiple running process

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, e) =>
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to Exit");

        var taskKeys = new Task(ReadKeys);
        var taskProcessFiles = new Task(ProcessFiles);

        taskKeys.Start();
        taskProcessFiles.Start();

        var tasks = new[] { taskKeys };
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }

    private static void ProcessFiles()
    {
        var files = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(n => "File" + n + ".txt");

        var taskBusy = new Task(BusyIndicator);
        taskBusy.Start();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Procesing file {0}", file);
        }
    }

    private static void BusyIndicator()
    {
        var busy = new ConsoleBusyIndicator();
        busy.UpdateProgress();
    }

    private static void ReadKeys()
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = new ConsoleKeyInfo();

        while (!Console.KeyAvailable && key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {

            key = Console.ReadKey(true);

            switch (key.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    Console.WriteLine("UpArrow was pressed");
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    Console.WriteLine("DownArrow was pressed");
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    Console.WriteLine("RightArrow was pressed");
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    Console.WriteLine("LeftArrow was pressed");
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.Escape:
                    break;

                default:
                    if (Console.CapsLock && Console.NumberLock)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(key.KeyChar);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class ConsoleBusyIndicator
{
    int _currentBusySymbol;

    public char[] BusySymbols { get; set; }

    public ConsoleBusyIndicator()
    {
        BusySymbols = new[] { '|', '/', '-', '\\' };
    }
    public void UpdateProgress()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            var originalX = Console.CursorLeft;
            var originalY = Console.CursorTop;

            Console.Write(BusySymbols[_currentBusySymbol]);

            _currentBusySymbol++;

            if (_currentBusySymbol == BusySymbols.Length)
            {
                _currentBusySymbol = 0;
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(originalX, originalY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little about the approach you had i am trying to do the same with my console application.An explanation for the code would be great.

Comment: @nayefharb setup a bunch of tasks, start them, and WaitAll will wait until they have all returned. Hence the individual tasks won't return and it will continue forever until a CancelKeyPress is triggered.

Comment: `Console.CursorVisible = false;` will be best to avoid the cursor blink glitches. Add this line as first line in the `static void Main(string[] args)` block.

Comment: `var tasks = new[] { taskKeys };` should probably be `var tasks = new[] { taskKeys, taskProcessFiles };`

Answer (score 14):

Here is an approach for you to do something on a different thread and start listening to the key pressed in a different thread. And the Console will stop its processing when your actual process ends or the user terminates the process by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

```
class SplitAnalyser
{
    public static bool stopProcessor = false;
    public static bool Terminate = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Split Analyser starts");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("Press Esc to quit.....");
        Thread MainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startProcess));
        Thread ConsoleKeyListener = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListerKeyBoardEvent));
        MainThread.Name = "Processor";
        ConsoleKeyListener.Name = "KeyListener";
        MainThread.Start();
        ConsoleKeyListener.Start();

        while (true) 
        {
            if (Terminate)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Terminating Process...");
                MainThread.Abort();
                ConsoleKeyListener.Abort();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                return;
            }

            if (stopProcessor)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ending Process...");
                MainThread.Abort();
                ConsoleKeyListener.Abort();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                return;
            }
        } 
    }

    public static void ListerKeyBoardEvent()
    {
        do
        {
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                Terminate = true;
            }
        } while (true); 
    }

    public static void startProcess()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (!stopProcessor && !Terminate)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine("Processing...." + i++);
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            if(i==10)
                stopProcessor = true;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Addressing cases that some of the other answers don't handle well:

- **Responsive**: explicit/direct execution of keypress handling code; avoids the vagaries of  polling or blocking delays
- **Optionality**: global keypress is *opt-in*; by default the app exits normally (if no action)
- **Separation of concerns**:  less invasive listening code; operates independently of your console app's core logic.

---

Many of the solutions on this page involve polling `Console.KeyAvailable` or blocking on `Console.ReadKey`. While it's true that the .NET `Console` is not very cooperative here, you can use `Task.Run` to move towards a more modern `Async` mode of listening.

The main issue to be aware of is that, by default, your console thread isn't set up for `Async` operation--meaning that, when you fall out of the bottom of your `main` function, instead of awaiting `Async` completions, your AppDoman and process will end. A proper way to address this would be to use Stephen Cleary's [AsyncContext](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html) to establish full `Async` support in your single-threaded console program. But for simpler cases, like waiting for a keypress, installing a full [trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) may be overkill.

The example below would be for a console program used in some kind of iterative batch file. In this case, when the program is done with its work, normally it should exit **without** requiring a keypress, and then we allow an optional key press to **prevent** the app from exiting. We can pause the cycle to examine things, possibly resuming, or use the pause as a known 'control point' at which to cleanly break out of the batch file.

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to prevent exit...");
    var tHold = Task.Run(() => Console.ReadKey(true));

    // ... do your console app activity ...

    if (tHold.IsCompleted)
    {
#if false   // For the 'hold' state, you can simply halt forever...
        Console.WriteLine("Holding.");
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
#else                       // ...or allow continuing on (to exit)
        while (Console.KeyAvailable)
            Console.ReadKey(true);     // flush/consume any extras
        Console.WriteLine("Holding. Press 'Esc' to exit.");
        while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
            ;
#endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Visual Studio, then you can use "Start Without Debugging" in the Debug menu.

It will automatically write "Press any key to continue . . ." to the console for you upon completion of the application and it will leave the console open for you until a key is pressed.

Answer (score 3):

with following code you can listen for Spacebar in middle of your console execution and pause until another key is pressed with additional of option of listening for Escape Key in order to breake the main loop.

```
static ConsoleKeyInfo cki = new ConsoleKeyInfo();

while(true) {
      if (WaitOrBreak()) break;
      //your main code
}

private static bool WaitOrBreak(){
    if (Console.KeyAvailable) cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
    {
        Console.Write("waiting..");
        while (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(250);Console.Write(".");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        cki = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
    }
    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, in console apps the easiest way to read the last key pressed is as follows (Example with arrow keys):

```
ConsoleKey readKey = Console.ReadKey ().Key;
if (readKey == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow) {
    <Method1> ();  //Do something
} else if (readKey == ConsoleKey.RightArrow) {
    <Method2> ();  //Do something
}
```

I use to avoid loops, instead I write the code above within a method, and I call it at the end of both "Method1" and "Method2", so, after executing "Method1" or "Method2", Console.ReadKey().Key is ready to read the keys again.

Answer (score -1):

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
var key = Console.ReadKey(); 
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
bool gotKey = Console.KeyAvailable;

while ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds < 2)                
{
    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
    {
       Environment.Exit(0);
    } 
    else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
       break;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).