# Emergency Escape [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, escaping

I am writing a console application that lists a sequence of numbers according to a defined set of rules. It has been programmed to stop itself after a static value is found (next number=this number).

However, there are a few exceptions where the sequence is not contained, and the console window just goes on running the digits. In this case I found no way to exit the sequence but to close the application manually.

Is it possible to implement a emergency escape feature where, say, the Esc key is pressed at any time will trigger the application to give up the current task?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/c-sharp-listen-for-key-ress-in-console-app

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> should terminate the application. Specifying another key sequence is a little more complicated and probably not worth the effort if all you want to do is exit immediately and nothing more.