# method waiting for an winform event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, wait

in a programm i've been developing, a method is needed to wait until ENTER is clicked inside a specific textbox (generally, winform event called). i know i shold be doing this with threads, but dont know how to make a method that will do that. more specificly, i don't know how to call the event method on the thread, and cannot call in on Main, because it's blocked until this method is called.

the method stopping the Main thread is:

```
 void WaitForInput()
 {
     while (!gotInput)
     {
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
     }
 }
```

thanks for helpers.

Comment: Why don't you call the method on KeyPress event of TextBox?

Comment: look at this stackoverflow posting..seems like similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/c-sharp-listen-for-key-press-in-console-app

Answer (score 1):

Just subscribe to [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) (or [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)) event of your textbox:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: i already did that, and it isn't helping. i need to stop the Main thread, but still be able to call textBoxInput_KeyDown(). your solution do not stop the thread.

Comment: @user1461837 you should never stop main thread. It will hang your application

Comment: i'm starting to consider to make the Main the thread waiting for input and makeing each event run on his own thread.

Comment: @user1461837 can you explain what you are trying to achieve? Why you need to stop thread? Please describe workflow of your application

Answer (score 0):

You can start by changing the WaitForInput method to be threaded by using Tasks like this:

```
  private void WaitForInput()
  {
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
          {
              while (!gotInput)
              {
                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
              }
              MessageBox.Show("Test");
          });
  }
```

Then catch the KeyPressed event of the textbox and change the state of the boolean gotInput to true like this:

```
  private void KeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
          gotInput = true;
  }
```

Good luck

Comment: by KeyDown(), you have meant the textbox KayDown event?

Comment: it says that Tasks doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `async/await` keywords from .NET 4.5. You could do something like this:

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource; // member variable in your Form

// Initialize and wait for input on Form.Load.
async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  await WaitForInput(tokenSource.Token);

  // ENTER was pressed!
}

// Our TextBox has input, cancel the wait if ENTER was pressed.
void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  // Wait for ENTER to be pressed.
  if(e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter) return;

  if(tokenSource != null)
    tokenSource.Cancel();
}

// This method will wait for input asynchronously.
static async Task WaitForInput(CancellationToken token)
{
  await Task.Delay(-1, token); // wait indefinitely
}
```

Answer (score 0):

currently i'm stuck with a dinosaur computer that has XP on it (.NET 2008 and cannot upgrade until april or so). i've ended up following a solution from the comments, and makethe main thread wait and run the entries on threads.
thanks!