# How do I add a loop to my code so the code keeps going until the user types '!'?

Tags: c#

I have no idea what I am doing it was hard enough to get to where I am. Feel free to correct something with the code, help me add a loop to it or even just start all over from scratch.

Here's the problem I am trying to make a console based application that asks the user to type a lowercase letter from the keyboard. If the character entered is a lowercase letter, display “OK”; if it is not a lowercase letter, display an error message. The program should continue until the user types ‘!’.

Here's what I have so far:

```
if (Char.IsLower(c))
{
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
else if (Char.IsUpper(c))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The character is not a lowercase letter.");
}
else if (Char.IsDigit(c))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The character is not a lowercase letter.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The character is not a lowercase letter.");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: First thing you would do is google for loops in C#

Comment: Use Console.ReadLine(), check if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), Re-curse if necessary.

Comment: Here's a hint: `while`

Comment: No I don't know how what do you think I have been trying to do. The problem is I can't find the right implementation of a loops using google. All the examples are using numbers how do I do it with characters, Uppercase, and Lowercase letters?

Comment: Here's an example; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/c-sharp-listen-for-key-press-in-console-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work. It will loop until the user enters an exclamation point.

```
while (true)
{
    var inputCharacter = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    if (inputCharacter == '!')
    {
        break;
    }

    if (char.IsLower(inputCharacter))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The character is not a lowercase letter.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for renaming the variable I confused myself so much by naming it c.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional is much easier than you've got there.. here's an example for your conditional. It appears to me that you already have some sort of loop happening, since `c` exists in your example:

```
if (c == '!') {
    break;
}
else if (char.IsLower(c)) {
    // it's fine!
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
else {
    // it's not a lowercase character
    Console.WriteLine("Not a lowercase character");
}
```

Comment: I see I don't have to write else if (Char.IsUpper(c)), else if (Char.IsDigit(c)).  I can just put else which means everything else that is not a lowercase character then Console.WriteLine and output the message.  Instead of having to do it 3 times like I did.

Comment: Yep. That's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop on the `Console.ReadKey` waiting for `!`

```
char c;
while ((c = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar) != '!')
{
    if (char.IsLower(c))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The character is not a lowercase letter.");
}
```

Comment: Is better to use else statement instead of continue operator.