# Escape button on C# console application

Tags: c#

Hi guys I bet I'm being really stupid. Can you help me get rid of the errors? Sorry for this I'm a student new to learning c#. Do I need to declare any variables to correct the logic?

```
void WindowCloseOnEsc_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)   
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
         Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your title indicates you are creating a Console application.  If that is so, the KeyDown events are not available.  Can you clarify if you have a console application or a Windows Forms application?

Comment: IT's a console application

Comment: When asking questions in the future keep in mind that it is a good idea to tell what the errors are and if they are compile errors or runtime errors.

Comment: You probably want to do it this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5891612/945456

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# listen for key press in console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/c-sharp-listen-for-key-press-in-console-app)

Comment: I've fixed it now turns out I was coding for a form application when I wanted a console

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If this is a console application, you should be looking at using the [ConsoleKeyInfo.Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.key%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Taken from the link provided, there is a sample from MSDN that shows a way to close/quit the console program when the <kbd>esc</kbd> key is pressed. Here is the basic idea:

```
public static void Main() 
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

    Console.WriteLine("Press the Escape (Esc) key to quit: \n");
    do 
    {
        cki = Console.ReadKey();
        // do something with each key press until escape key is pressed
    } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`Environment.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , and you should change your `if` statement like this:

```
void WindowCloseOnEsc_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)   
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
   {
       Environment.Exit(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah these things seem to crop up as errors... KeyEventArgs e... Keys...Close.

Comment: Thanks this is loads better :) still getting a problem on KeyEventArgs e and keys I don't know what type of variable to use to make it relevant for example bool, float, or string!

Comment: what is the problem, or error message?

Comment: The type or namespace name ‘KeyEventArge’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assemble reference?) and... The name ‘keys’ does not exist in the current context

Comment: change KeyEventArge to KeyEventArgs

Comment: sorry typing mistake I meant "KeyEventArgs"