# How to assign an event to a button press

Tags: c#, events, button

So, I have been working on a game made in console application and what I want to do is - when I press a button (Example: Escape), some code executes and it does what it is told to do.

I've searched over the internet and the only thing I found is this, which is not working and I don't know why:

```
void WindowCloseOnEsc_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  // does not know what
{                                                          // is this "KeyEventargs"
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a WinForms event.  You can't use that with a console.

Comment: is that workf ro you ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of

[Console.ReadKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to listen key pressed by the user of application.

```
class Example 
{
   public static void Main() 
   {
      ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
      // Prevent example from ending if CTL+C is pressed.
      Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

      Console.WriteLine("Press any combination of CTL, ALT, and SHIFT, and a console key.");
      Console.WriteLine("Press the Escape (Esc) key to quit: \n");
      do 
      {
         cki = Console.ReadKey();
         Console.Write(" --- You pressed ");
         if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Alt) != 0) Console.Write("ALT+");
         if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Shift) != 0) Console.Write("SHIFT+");
         if((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0) Console.Write("CTL+");
         Console.WriteLine(cki.Key.ToString());
       } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a console application you are supposed to use input methods from the `Console.Read*()` lineage.

The code above can be bound to a windows form application, which has a message pump and generally works differently (is event oriented, not line oriented).

This answers a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891612/3227403