# capture keystroke without blocking

Tags: c#, console-application, keystore, readline, console.readline

I usually use `Console.ReadLine();` to capture a single keystroke. But this function blocks execution and keeps waiting for it to happen.

Is it possible, inside a loop, to capture it if it's pressed and continue execution if it's not?

The best would be something similar to GUI apps, that keep running and anytime a shortcut is executed it's intercepted and an event throws to be captured. But I doubt console apps are able to do that.

The second best solution would be a `Console.ReadLine();` that waits for 1 second and then returns. If user is holding a keyboard button while the function is called, the function identifies the keystroke and returns with its char, otherwise the function returns with null.

Comment: Use `Console.In.Peek()` to check if the user has entered anything.

Comment: you can check `Console.KeyAvailable`

Comment: [Listen for key press in .NET console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [MSDN Key press info for console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Console.KeyAvailable);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)?

You can use `Console.KeyAvailable` to determine if you actually want to get the key in the queue.