# C# Console - Run Event on Key Press

Tags: c#, console

I just wanted to ask if it was *possible* to make an event run if the player presses a specific button. This should be tested at every point in the console application but not if there is a Console.ReadLine() event used at the moment.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen for key press in .NET console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Console.ReadKey()` method like this

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

if(keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.A)
{

}
```

For more info see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is there a possibility to constantly check if this is pressed?

Comment: See this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/288867/Producing-KeyPress-events-for-the-Console. But in the console application there are rare cases for key evetns