# Display new line of text document after pressing enter key

Tags: c#

I'm currently pooping out, I am having trouble displaying lines from a text document. What I mean is whenever I press enter it displays a new line of the text document.

Thanks

This is I guess some code, this is referenced to a text document and received a definition, from here it receives it and gets it ready to display but I just need it to read from say **result** one line at a time every time I press enter

First line wont work this is the first line ->>>>

```
var result = GetLinesWithWord(i1, @"" + Path + "/dict2.txt");

// Display the results.
foreach (var line1 in result)
{
    //word maxlength
    const int MaxLength = 82;
    var name1 = line1;

    if (name1.Length > MaxLength)       
        name1 = name1.Substring(0, MaxLength); 

    Console.WriteLine(name1 + "\r");

    string boc1 = name1;
    string foc1 = i1;

    System.IO.File.AppendAllText (@"" + Path + "/" + n + ".txt", foc1 + "\n" + boc1 + "\n");
```

Comment: Can u please show some code ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @MairajAhmad there u go

Comment: Are you getting desired data in `var result`? You just need to display form `var result` ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad I am getting desired result, the user creates own document after editing results in many lines on a text document. I just want it to read the doc named **result** one line at a time, displaying a new line every time I press enter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly (especcialy your comment to @MairajAhmad) you want to dump the text file line by line, waiting for the user to press a key after each line.

Look at the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891612/342594). I think, that is what you need. It's basically a call to Console.ReadKey(true). The mentioned post listen's for the escape key, but it should still illustrate what to do.