# C# exit if key is pressed

Tags: c#, console

I have an issue with the following code:

```
using System;
class Yellow
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Check_1");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("Check_2");
        char beep = '\a';
        int i = 3;
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(beep);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.WriteLine("Check_" + i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

After waiting for an input character to start, this program outputs a beep and a message of `Check_<i>` with a wait of 200 milliseconds between each loop. If a key is pressed during that loop, the program will terminate.

However, when I wait for the loop to have run many times (around 36 times), the loop doesn't break when I press a key. When I try to manually close the console with the `X` button, the program is non-responsive.

Why would it matter if the loop had run a few dozen times?

Comment: coherent sentences would help this question

Comment: Check this example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable(v=vs.110).aspx
I believe you are not really knowing what is going on when you do that while with Console.KeyAvailable

Comment: I'm quite sure the issue actually has nothing to do with which looping you are on, and that there is something going on that you aren't accounting for. I ran your code and it had no problem stopping even on higher counts in the loop

Comment: @AAlferez That example works basically the same way his is working, except that he isn't outputting the keys they put in and any key stops his program instead of just one specific key

Comment: @KevinWells how come this code works for you on higher counts, but in my case it doesnt ?

Comment: @AAlferez true if a key press is available; otherwise, false, so basicly as long as nothing is pressed the while loop should repeat, and if it is it should break out, so how come I could not know what is going on ?

Comment: I just let it run to a much higher number of loops and now it fails to terminate for me too. That is very interesting

Comment: Maybe System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200); is causing a problem here, idk why but maybe it does :/ EDIT: yeah changing a beep char into a letter and not a beep sound make program run without problems but sound is what I want, maye someone knows whats the problem here?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the beep output, when I remove it from the program I don't get the same problem. I will have to look into this further

Comment: Change it to Console.Beep() and lets see what's happening. Interesting

Comment: A strange thing is that now the program stops working normally like at Check_28 to me, and its not always the same when it does so, so I guess this problem might be connected to memory, RAM, heap, stack? (I might be terribly wrong but just making a statment here so the ones with more knowledge and wisdom may find an answer)

Comment: Yeah Console.Beep() makes everything okay expect it beeps slower I have to put System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50); (less than 50 ms doesnt have much effect) and it feels like it still beeps slower than '\a'

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app