# console specific key input without blocking

Tags: c#, console-application

I need to input specific keys (arrows.left and arrows.right) in my console application without blocking a loop.

Here's the code:

```
while (fuel>0) {
    moveAndGenerate();

    for (int i=0;i<road.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < road.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", road[i, j]));
        }
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Paliwo: "+ (fuel=fuel-5) + "%");

    moveAndGenerate();
    replaceArrays();            

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.Clear();
}
```

it generates a simple game:

```
| :x|
| : |
|x: |
| :↑|
```

Within the loop as long as there's fuel. I want the arrow to move right/left without waiting for `Console.ReadKey()`. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen for key press in .NET console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app)

Comment: `if (Console.KeyAvailable) {char key = Console.ReadKey(false);}`?

Answer (score 1):

As RB stated, you can setup a listener for the key press instead, and check if true if so they you reset the key press to null and move the car in that direction

[Listen for key press in .NET console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible workaround is to use a `BackgroundWorker` to listen for input. This way you can handle both user input and the main code at the "same" time. It's similar to a separate thread.

You'll need to add `using System.ComponentModel;` to your program.

```
static BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker(); // Create the background worker
static string input = ""; // where the user command is stored

public static void Main()
{
    // All the code preceding the main while loop is here
    // Variable declarations etc.


    //Setup a background worker
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += BackgroundWorker1_DoWork; // This tells the worker what to do once it starts working
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;  // This tells the worker what to do once its task is completed

    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); // This starts the background worker

    // Your main loop
    while (fuel>0) 
    {
        moveAndGenerate();

        for (int i=0;i<road.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < road.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", road[i, j]));
            }
            Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Paliwo: "+ (fuel=fuel-5) + "%");

        moveAndGenerate();
        replaceArrays();            

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.Clear();
    }

    // This is what the background worker will do in the background
    private static void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); // prevent the thread from eating too much CPU time
        }
        else
        {
            input = Console.In.ReadLine();

            // Do stuff with input here or, since you can make it a static
            // variable, do stuff with it in the while loop.
        }
    }

    // This is what will happen when the worker completes reading
    // a user input; since its task was completed, it will need to restart
    private static void BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs 
    {
        if(!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); // restart the worker
        }

    }
}
```