# Visual Basic 2012: Immediately Exiting while Loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, while-loop, interrupt, exit

I'm working on a console application for visual basic that will run a piece of code during a while loop.  If the escape key is pressed I would like the while loop to cease immediately, at any point.

I'm not sure how I can have the program listen for the escape keypress continuously, without having to put in a million checkpoints.   I realize that in the below example (just something I wrote in for a sample) that during the "readline" checks I have the opportunity to change the value. 
Any help would be appreciated!

```
Dim inp As Char
Dim x, y, z As Integer

While inp <> Chr(27)
    console.writeline ("Press escape at any time to exit")
    console.writeline ("Please enter a numeric value: ")
    x = console.readline()

    If x > 1 Then
        console.writeline ("greater")
    Else
        console.writeline ("lesser")
    End If

    console.writeline ("Do you have other values? Y or N")
    inp = console.readline()

    If inp = "y" Then
        '...other stuff
    Else
        console.writeline ("Press escape to exit or any other key to continue")
        inp = console.readline()
    End If

End While
```

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app

Based on what you're trying to do, putting the loop in another thread makes the most sense to me. Then you can just poll on the key states and terminate when necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, based on this information it appears multi-threading is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can also define a public Boolean variable and put it in true when escape key using it key press event. In your loop you could check value of this Boolean in some strategic point and go out case true.

Comment: Miguel,

That was my original approach; however, it didn't allow me the option to interrupt any code until I reached a "checkpoint" that could test the condition and exit the loop. 

I could see the merit if I had code that needed to be allowed to finish before escape should be allowed, but here I'm looking for an immediate escape.