# How can the user input the word "stop" and the code shuts off?

Tags: c#

I just need help because I couldn't find the answer I was looking for.
 I want this code to stop as soon as the user inputs the word stop.
If their is anymore details you want me to add just let me know.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LibraryWork
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bookList = new List<string>();
            string ansSearch = String.Empty;
            string search = String.Empty;
            int i = 1;
            for (int zero = 0; i > zero; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Type ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.Write("'New'");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write(" if you would you like to enter a new book. Type ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.Write("'List' ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("to see a list of books entered. Type ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.Write("'Search' ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("to look up a specific book.");
                Console.WriteLine();
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();

                if (answer == "New")
                {
                    Console.Write("Please format the Entry of your book as follows: ");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("'Name of the Book',");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.Write("'Author (first, last)',");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                    Console.Write("'Category',");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
                    Console.Write("'Dewey Decimal Number'.");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    bookList.Add("Entry " + i + ": " + Console.ReadLine());
                    continue;
                }
                if (answer == "List")
                {
                    bookList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                if (answer == "Search")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to search for (Title: Full Title; Author: first, last): ");
                    search = Console.ReadLine();
                    var results = bookList.Where(x => x.Contains(search)).ToList();
                    bool isEmpty = !results.Any();
                    if (isEmpty)
                    {
                        i--;
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, we could not find that.");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        continue;
                    }
                    foreach (var result in results)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(result);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    results.Clear();
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                i--;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Response, please try again");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if you need an endless loop you could use `while(true){...}` of `for (;;){...}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(answer == "Stop")
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Will exit the program. (Using `return;` will have the same affect)

Or, you can just use `break;` to escape the for loop:

```
if(answer == "Stop")
{
    break;
}
```

I'd recommend going with using `break;`, so that you can execute any other bits of code before the program closes.

**EDIT**

Another user has mentioned this, but your for loop is badly constructed. You don't need to decrement the value of `i` to make the for loop run endlessly.

Start by getting rid of every `i--;` in your code.

You have two options for an infinite loop:

**1.** `while(true)` - This is most commonly used, it's more readable and conventional to use this method.

**2.** `for(;;)` - Does the same thing, essentially, but it is far less common.

Comment: Or `return` in order to return from the `Main`

Comment: You're very welcome. Please go ahead and mark this as `Answered` by clicking the tick if you're satisfied.

Comment: Whats with the case if (answer == "Search") ? ... there is a second Readline ... the reqired stop is not possible like described in this answer.

Comment: He has what he needs to implement checks inside there as well. @Fruchtzwerg

Comment: I don´t like this way to imlemenent the code multiple times ... I think a solution like waheed described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app would be a better approach.

Comment: I agree, I'm simply answering OP's question to specification.