# C# How to make an open while loop that stops when user wants

Tags: c#

I'm writing a small loop in C# that I want to stay open until the user specifies.

```
public void ScoreCalc()
    {
        string goon = " ";
        int counter = 1;
        int score = 0;

        while (goon == " ")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a score");
            score += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine(score + " " + counter);
            counter++;
        }

    }
```

I know this code is not correct.

Comment: "Until the user specifies" via what? You could do `var read = Console.ReadLine(); if(read == "quit") break;`

Comment: How does the user specify? When that condition occurs, use `break;` to break out of the loop (or test that condition in your `while ({condition})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen for key press in .NET console app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app)

Comment: @trailmax That's not the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to set `goon` to something other than `" "` if anything other than an integer is entered by the user.

The easiest way to check if an integer has been entered is by using the [Int32.TryParse method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public void ScoreCalc()
{
    string goon = " ";
    int counter = 1;
    int score = 0;
    int userInput = 0;
    bool isInt = true;

    while (goon == " ")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a score");

        isInt = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput);

        if(isInt)
        {
            score += userInput;

            Console.WriteLine(score + " " + counter);
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            goon = "exit";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ScoreCalc()
{
    int counter = 1;
    int score = 0;
    String input;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a score");
        input=Console.ReadLine();
        if(input != "end"){
        score += int.Parse(input);
        Console.WriteLine(score + " " + counter);
        counter++;
        }else{
        break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can omit the `else` statement just checking `if(input == "end")    break;`

Comment: You should use the `int.TryParse()` method to avoid unnecessary errors

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your method assuming "quit" text as an exit signal from the user to break the while loop. Hope this helps!

```
    public void ScoreCalc()
    {

        string goon = " ";
        int counter = 1;
        int score = 0;
        var userInput = string.Empty;
        var inputNumber = 0;
        const string exitValue = "quit";

        while (goon == " ")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a score or type quit to exit.");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userInput.ToLower() == exitValue)
            {
                break;
            }
            score += int.TryParse(userInput, out inputNumber) ? inputNumber : 0;

            Console.WriteLine(score + " " + counter);
            counter++;
        }

    }
```