# How to make Console App listen for keypresses from other processes?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# programming and I'm attempting to write a Console App that will run in the background and perform an action when a key is pressed (ideally I would like to know how to do this for any key but, if that's not possible, then a specific key).

Here's an idea of what I want (please excuse and feel free to correct any bad coding as I'm just starting out).

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while(true)
    {
         ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey();
         if( cki.Key == ConsoleKey.R )
         {
              Console.WriteLine("Run me");
         }
     }
 }
```

The above seems to work but only if the Console App is in focus. I would like it to happen even if the app isn't in focus.

I've done some research and read about registering 'hotkeys' but also read that this is dangerous in case another application is requiring that key?

I've also read similar questions on here but they seem to deal with Windows Forms and not just Console Apps.

Can anyone help shed any light on this?

Comment: You should look into keyboard hooks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen for key press in .NET console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app)

Comment: @Filburt this is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx, calls to `RegisterHotKey()` will fail if the requested key combo has already been registered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
```

But to make it work from console you'll need to create hidden form that will handle messages for you. Check out [this class](https://github.com/evilboob/CsgoMusic/blob/master/OverlayPlayer/Key/HotkeyManager.cs). It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure how I would implement that class in my software though? Do I just have a "using OverlayPlayer.Key" at the top of my software (i.e. the same as Using System.IO etc) and then somehow "include" that file into my 'solution'? Thanks

Comment: grab whole HotkeyManager.cs file and add it to your solution.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll give it a go when I finish work this evening. Cheers :-)