# Reading the keys form a keyboard C#

Tags: c#, keyboard

I have a console app in C# that does a animation with a word, in a loop. Its basically showing the word going from left to righ.
My idea is that if the user press upArrow the animation would start to go up , if he press left the word would satrt to go left... and so on 
My question is, how can i have a loop running and also have the program listen for the keyboard key that will be pressed at any given moment?

Comment: I think you are looking for something called an EventHandler.

Comment: ill look into it, thanks.

Comment: You can refer in here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a good and considerable code for you although you need to complete it yourself. It just follows the order of the Left Arrow key. You need to add some extra code for following the other orders. Also you have to care about `indexoutofrangeexception`. As you can see I have written some extra code to handle the left side of console. I hope you enjoy it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string txt = "STACKOVERFLOW";
    var x = 1;
    var startPos = 0;
    var col = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        do
        {
            while (!Console.KeyAvailable && (startPos <= 100 || startPos >= 0))
            {

                startPos = col + x;
                if (startPos < 0)
                {
                    startPos = 0;
                    x = 1;
                }
                Console.SetCursorPosition(startPos, 0);
                Console.WriteLine(txt);
                col = startPos;
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.Clear();
            }
        } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.LeftArrow);
        x = -1;

    }
}
```

Comment: @Daniel-Linux YW bro. Could you accept the solution please? :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found a solution for your program yet, but here is a good tutorial you might find useful.

[Basic C# Game Programming Moving Object on the form](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eIzmcTe0mg)

Comment: Thanks, its a useful tutorial but in my case i don't have Wforms so i cannot use his method