# How to make a program run till escape is pressed?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make this program to wait till the Escape key is pressed, instead of using `for` loop (it's a Console Application).

```
namespace CharASCII
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                char character;
                Console.Write("Enter the character: ");
                character = Char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "The ASCII value of '" + character +
                    "' using (int)character: " + (int)character);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app

Comment: Have you tried using a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for Esc keypress you need to do:

//doing things untill you press Esc:

```
while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape))    
{
  \\doing your code here !!!avoid infinit loop!!!
}
```

making it empty will be waiting untill Esc press.