# Keep main thread alive c# while using Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I'm using Timer in my main method in my console app. Right now I use some while loop to keep my main thread alive, that I found on the Web. Because when it dies, my thread, executing method that I pass to the timer dies too.

Question: Is it blocking my Main thread or is it okay to use this that way? Or is there better way to keep main thread alive without blocking anything?

```
public void Run()
{
    Logger.Trace("Timer Started.");
    Timer.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);
    Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to stop...");
    while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape))
    { }
}
```

Comment: You can use Dispatcher TImer that will do some other work in background, and will Invoke into your main thread, when there is need (for example each 1s): http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/dispatchertimer/

Comment: @sTrenat It will be console or Windows Service app and Threading.Timer already does all the job I need. I just wanted to know a thread-safe way to keep my main thread alive without blocking it.

Comment: *"is it okay to use this that way"* - it's ok. Using [`Console.ReadKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw(v=vs.110).aspx) at the end of console application is a common way to prevent it from finishing.

Comment: .. but, you are checking (why?) for `KeyAvailable`, which makes the loop very CPU intensive. Remove that check.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm using KeyAvailable according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24424239/5506726

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accept Sinatr's answer. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable(v=vs.110).aspx

using KeyAvailable is a ordinary way of doing these checks without blocking anything