# Reading Key Press in Console App

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, listener

I'm writing a small application which will wait for a key press, then perform an action based on what key is pressed. For example, if no key is pressed, it will just continue waiting, if key 1 is pressed, it will perform action 1, or if key 2 is pressed it will perform action 2. I have found several helpful posts so far, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app) being an example. From this, I have the following code so far.

```
do
{
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.NumPad1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ConsoleKey.NumPad1.ToString());
        }
        if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.NumPad2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ConsoleKey.NumPad1.ToString());
        }
    }

} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

There's a couple of issue with this, which you may have guessed already.

**1)**
Using the `ReadKey` to detect which key is pressed results in a temporary pause, meaning the key will have to be pressed. I really need to find a way to avoid this. Possibly using `KeyAvailable`, but I'm not sure how you can use this to detect which key has been pressed - any ideas?

**2)**
For some reason, the `Escape` key does not escape out of the application. It does if I remove the `if` statements, however running the code as is above does not let me exit the application using the designated key - any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the behavior is simple:

You get inside the nested loop as long as there is no key pressed.
Inside you are waiting for a key and read it - So again no key is available.
even if you press escape, you are still inside the nested loop and never get out of it.

What you should of done is loop until you have a key available, then read it and check its value:

```
ConsoleKey key;
do
{
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        // Do something, but don't read key here
    }

    // Key is available - read it
    key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

    if (key == ConsoleKey.NumPad1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ConsoleKey.NumPad1.ToString());
    }
    else if (key == ConsoleKey.NumPad2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ConsoleKey.NumPad1.ToString());
    }

} while (key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want, and it helps me understand what `KeyAvailable` is doing - it loops (waits), while there is no key available. as soon as there is a key available it breaks the loop, and goes on to check the key. Thanks very much!

Comment: Sitting in that tight inner while loop doesn't seem like a good idea.  Why not just put all that code inside a single `if` statement and eliminate the inner while loop.  `do { if (Console.KeyAvailable) { key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key; ...} } while (key != ConsoleKey.Escape);`.  One other thing to consider, referencing the `Key` property directly on the `ReadKey` call causes you to lose other information about the keypress, such as which modifier keys are also pressed (Ctrl, Alt, Shift).

Comment: You make a good point @ChrisDunaway,  but in your example, the variable `key` is only assigned a value after a key has been pressed. So its not possible to construct a do-while loop using criteria which is undefined. I guess you could always just assign it a temporary value to start the loop (?), but that seems messy - more messy (though maybe not as messy as constant while loop)... Please update me if Ive misunderstood. Thanks

Comment: You would still define the `key` variable outside the loop as you have done so that it will not equal `ConsoleKey.Escape`.  You only need to call `ReadKey` if there is a key available.  As soon as a key is pressed, the next time `KeyAvailable` is checked it will be true and enter the if statement.  Does that make sense?