# Detect key combination being pressed in C# console app

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, listener, keypress

I have a pretty simple console app thats quietly waits for a users to press a key, then performs an action based on the what key was pressed. I had some issues with it, but some helpful users over on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939267/reading-key-press-in-console-app/46939556#46939556) pointed out where I was going wrong.

The code I currently have to handle a single key press is as follows

```
ConsoleKey key;
do
{
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        // Do something, but don't read key here
    }

    // Key is available - read it
    key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

    if (key == ConsoleKey.NumPad1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ConsoleKey.NumPad1.ToString());
    }
    else if (key == ConsoleKey.NumPad2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ConsoleKey.NumPad2.ToString());
    }

} while (key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

I'm wondering how I can detect when a combination of 2 or more keys is pressed. I'm not talking about the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, but rather something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad1</kbd>. If a user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad1</kbd>, perform action `X`.

I'm really unsure how to go about doing this, as the current `while` loop will only loop until a single key is pressed, so wont detect the second key (assuming that its litterally impossible to press two keys at the exact same time.

Is anyone able to provide a steer in the right direction to help achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you capture the `ConsoleKeyInfo`, you will get additional information, including the `Modifiers` keys. You can query this to see if the <kbd>Control</kbd> key was pressed:

```
ConsoleKey key;

do
{
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        // Do something, but don't read key here
    }

    // Key is available - read it
    var keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
    key = keyInfo.Key;

    if ((keyInfo.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Ctrl + ");
    }
    if (key == ConsoleKey.NumPad1)
    {                    
        Console.WriteLine(ConsoleKey.NumPad1.ToString());
    }
    else if (key == ConsoleKey.NumPad2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ConsoleKey.NumPad2.ToString());
    }

} while (key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to check the [key modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.modifiers(v=vs.110).aspx). Check the pseudo code below:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
Console.WriteLine(keyInfo.Key);
Console.WriteLine(keyInfo.Modifier);
...
if((keyInfo.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0) Console.WriteLine("CTL+");
```