# Snake Program stops running without exception

Tags: c#, element, gameobject

I am trying to program snake in console. After a random amount of steps the snake takes, a new GameObject spawns (e.g. an apple that makes the snake grow or a mushroom which makes the snake faster).

I create a random gameObject (on random (left, top) coordinates and then I need to check if that gameObject spawns on top of a snakeBodyPart or on top of another gameObject. If that is the case, I create a new gameObject and try the same again. Only if it doesn´t collide with another gameObject or the Snake, it will spawn.

snakeElemnts = a list, which has all the snake- body-parts;
gameObjects = a list with all existing gameObjects;

If the noCollisionAmount == the amount of snakeElements and GameObjects, there should be no collision and the new GameObject should spawn.

Unfortunately at one point (early on), the snake just stops moving and nothing happens (no exception or anything).

I can´t debug because I have a KeyboardWatcher running, which checks if a key gets pressed. Therefore when I press break, I can only examine the keyboardwatcher.

Setting a breakpoint is not useful, because I never break when the problem arises.

```
if (this.randomStepNumber == 0)                
{
    int noCollision = 0; // this variable counts the amount of times there was no collision

    GameObject validGameObject;

          while (true)
          {
             validGameObject = this.snakeGameObjectFactory.Generate();

             foreach (SnakeElements element in snakeElements)
             {
                   if (validGameObject.XPosition != element.XPosition || validGameObject.YPosition != element.YPosition)
                    {
                      noCollision++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       break;
                    }
               }

              foreach (GameObject gameObject in gameObjects)
              {
                  if (noCollision == snakeElements.Count) // if there was no collision of the new gameobject with an element of the snake, the gameobjects will get checked
                  {
                       if (validGameObject.XPosition != gameObject.XPosition || validGameObject.YPosition != gameObject.YPosition)
                       {
                           noCollision++;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           break;
                        }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      break;
                   }
               }

               if (noCollision == snakeElements.Count + gameObjects.Count) // if there was no collision at all, the check is ended
               {
                   break;
               }
               else
               {
                  noCollision = 0;
               }
           }

       this.gameObjects.Add(validGameObject);

       this.randomStepNumber = this.random.Next(10, 30);
}
```

Comment: did you happen to write this in college?  I

Comment: Yes sir, you are right

Comment: ivy tech class?

Comment: I am in my first semester of computer science in Austria, basics in C#

Comment: What is the `else` part of the `if (randomStepNumber == 0)` Since if you add a gameobject you generate a new random step number and that is between 10 and 30, and I am assuming the code shown is running inside some other loop or in a function that is being called in a loop or event or something.

Comment: i may be wrong but it looks like you have an infinite loop when a collision happens.

Comment: There is no else part at the moment, I am reducing the randomStepNumber by 1 everytime the Thread sleeps, when it reaches 0, i go into this code section. The randomStepNumber get created at the beginning and after that, if I break the while(true) loop

Comment: @JohnLord I can´t find why though

Comment: The logic seems very convoluted and this line `if (noCollision > snakeElements.Count + gameObjects.Count)` followed with a continue statement seems like this could be your problem. I was thinking that maybe it would never be true, but reading through the code again, I think it is probably likely that this is happening.

Comment: when you detect a collision, then nocollision==snakeelements.count will never be true and your else is empty.

Comment: @pstrjds I removed that before and the same problem remains

Comment: @JohnLord But if there is a collision I set the noCollision to 0 and stay in the while(true) loop

Comment: actually i can't believe i didn't see this.  Remove this code
  if (noCollision > snakeElements.Count + gameObjects.Count)
                {
                    continue;
                }

Comment: @JohnLord I did and the problem remains

Comment: Just a note for debugging purposes. Not sure if you are using Visual Studio or not, but if you have a keyboard handler that is intercepting the break calls,then in the keyboard handler add an if statement that is checking for the "break" key. Add something inside that if statement and then set that as a breakpoint. Then when you press break, the code will breakpoint inside that if statement and you should be able to examine the other threads in the debugger.

Comment: @pstrjds I am using Visual Studio Enterprise, I will try it, thank you so much. "Break" is just the button (Ctrl+Alt+Break) though, I don´t know how to state that in an if- Statement

Comment: @d0neall - Sounds like a good candidate for a little more research or a new question :)  But before asking, I would take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5891538/416574) SO post that talks about keyboard input in a console application.

Comment: @pstrjds Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments that removing this block of code causes the problem to cease, I thought maybe it would be good to clean up the code a little and remove that potential infinite loop with the continue statement.  Making use of a little LINQ [Enumerable.Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2) and a do-while loop, we can simplify the logic of the above code.  There isn't really a need to be counting collisions, since the purpose of the code is to create a new object **iff** a collision is detected.  That means if we detect a collision with the snake, then we want to generate a new object, or if we detect a collision with another existing object, then we want to generate a new object.  So instead of counting, we use the `Any` statement to check if there is any collision with the snake or an existing object.  If there is, then generate a new object.  If not, then use that object and continue.  Note: In order to use the `Enumerable.Any` you will need to add a `using` statement for the namespace `System.Linq`.

```
if (randomStepNumber == 0)                
{    
    GameObject validGameObject;
    do
    {
        validGameObject = snakeGameObjectFactory.Generate();
    }
    while(snakeElements.Any(s => validGameObject.XPosition == s.XPosition && validGameObject.YPosition == s.YPosition) ||
         gameObjects.Any(o => validGameObject.XPosition == o.XPosition && validGameObject.YPosition == o.YPosition));

    gameObjects.Add(validGameObject);
    randomStepNumber = random.Next(10, 30);
}
```

As a side note.  I removed the `this` keyword as it appeared you were not using it in all cases in your code, and if you do not have to use it, it makes the code a little more readable because it is less wordy. If it needs to be added back because of variable collisions, then I would suggest renaming the variables as having member and local variables with the same name can also be confusing when trying to debug something.

Secondary note - here is a version of the code not using LINQ, in case that is not allowed for your homework.

```
if (randomStepNumber == 0)                
{    
    GameObject validGameObject = null;
    while(validGameObject == null)
    {
        validGameObject = snakeGameObjectFactory.Generate();
        foreach(var snake in snakeElements)
        {
            if (validGameObject.XPosition == snake.XPosition &&
                validGameObject.YPosition == snake.YPosition)
            {
                validGameObject = null;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (validGameObject != null)
        {
            foreach(var gameObject in gameObjects)
            {
                if (validGameObject.XPosition == gameObject.XPosition &&
                    validGameObject.YPosition == gameObject.YPosition)
                {
                    validGameObject = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    gameObjects.Add(validGameObject);
    randomStepNumber = random.Next(10, 30);
}
```

Comment: I want to create add a new gameObject if NO collision with either the snake or another gameObject is detected. That is why I am checking the Snake and all the GameObjects

Comment: looks good.  make sure he knows how to include linq though.  he's admittedly a new student

Comment: @pstrjds Sorry for my comment, I misread your comment! Thank you very much for your answer, I will try it

Comment: @JohnLord - That is why I added a link to the documentation in the beginning of the answer. I have also added a non-LINQ in case it is not allowed. Still unsure that this will solve the problem, but it at least cleans up the code. Added a note about adding the using statement though now too :)

Comment: @pstrjds Your second code seems to be working! You are a genius, is there any way to thank you?

Comment: @JohnLord Thanks a lot to you too, I really appreciate the amount of work volunteers put in on this site.

Comment: @d0neall - Glad it worked/helped. I added an additional comment up above to help you with future debugging in situations like this. As far as thanks, on SO the way you say thanks or "it helped me" is by upvoting and accepting answers. Just a note, I am by far not a genius, just experienced. One of the things I have learned over the years is that the more complicated looking the logic, the more likely it is I have messed something up in it. In your case you need to detect collisions, so we step back and think, what is the simplest way to detect "any" collisions and work from there.

Comment: @pstrjds I accepted your answer, I can´t upvote though because I am still a SO noob. Thank you very much.

Comment: accepting his answer is how you "upvote" on a question you ask yourself.  As a side note, your original code had a bunch of unneeded breaks in it.  The else case at the end of a block will never need a break as all break does is exit that if statement.  Having a break in an else is never ever needed.

Comment: @JohnLord - Just a clarification. A `break` in an `else` block __will__ exit from a loop. While from a control flow and readability standpoint, I think it would potentially be rarer to have a `break` in an else statement, I don't think we can say "is never ever needed".  For an example showing a `break` in an `else` exiting a loop you can check this [ideone](https://ideone.com/gv9ILK) code sample.

Comment: I actually wasn't sure about that behavior and asked some other people I worked with and they all thought it would fall down to the next if.  None of us knew, apparently.

Comment: @JohnLord - No worries, that is why I wanted to add the clarification. If you think about it, an else is really just another half of an if and if the break statement will exit a loop from the if part, then it should do the same from the else part.  The docs for [break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break) also clarify this with this statement "The break statement terminates the __closest enclosing loop or switch statement__ in which it appears. Control is passed to the statement that follows the terminated statement, if any."

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not understand how "continue" works.

```
  if (noCollision > snakeElements.Count + gameObjects.Count)
            {
                continue;
            }
```

you have that at the beginning of a while loop.  If it's found true you will be stuck in an infinite loop.

secondly, you have a While(true) in there that will never let you save a valid result since it's outside the loop.  You should replace the while with a do while and check for a valid result at the end of it, then loop if there was a collision.

Comment: I removed that part, the problem remains

Comment: @d0neall - It still should go. It absolutely can lead to an infinite loop. When you say `continue` inside of a loop it jumps back to the top of the loop and ignores the remaining loop code. In your case, if this ever evaluates to true then you will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: possible a 2nd issue?  If your code is up to date above, i'll look at it some more

Comment: Code is up to date, the snake still stops moving. If I remove all of the code above from the program, there is no problem but I need the collisionDetection. There must be some kind of infinite loop but I cant debug it.

Comment: i'm not sure what the purpose of the while(true) loop.  You should only loop when you need to generate a new location.  See my edited answer for more details

Comment: @JohnLord Purpose is: When the generated Object is on top of the snake or another gameObject, I want to create another one

Comment: but you aren't checking to see if that happens in the loop conditional.  that loop will go forever.  while WHAT is true?  You are literally asking if true is true.  Since it always is, this loop will go forever. edit: added word "conditional"

Comment: try this:  Replace your "DO" with  "WHILE" and then at the end of your brackets, put } while (noCollision == 0);

Comment: also, the reason i asked if you went to ivy tech is i just graduated and another member of my class did a console snake program but said he hadn't figured out how to prevent food from ending up on the snake or walls.  Pretty coincidental you have the same project and issue.

Comment: @JohnLord I tried and it still doesn´t work :/ Still I am very grateful you are trying to help me.

Comment: if i had all the code i could debug better, but give pstrjds answer a shot.  It is more advanced code and will require you to include LINQ in your includes, but it looks pretty good to me.