# How to add a check condition in c#

Tags: c#

I want the if from line 23 to check if the user has input the letter x and if they did, the code to stop and do the multiplication for the numbers already inputed. How can I do that? I've tried several methods, but I keep on messing other things up, this is the final format of the code, in which I just need to have that check-up done. Thank you in advance

```
 using System;

 class Program
 {
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        string[] array = new string[100];
        bool a = Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.X;
        if (a==true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            while(a==false)
            {
                double multiply = 1;
                for (int i= 0; i<array.Length; i++)
                { 
                    array[i] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (a == true) break;
                    multiply *= Convert.ToDouble(array[i]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(multiply);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
   }
 }
```

**EDIT: Another solution to this problem and quite easier is:**

```
class Program
 {
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        int product = 1;
        string inputData = Console.ReadLine();

        while(inputData != "x")
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(inputData);
            product *= number;
            inputData = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(product);
        Console.ReadLine();
   }
 }
```

Comment: You are setting `a` only once, it needs to be set after every new input.

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app

Comment: @KristófTóth thank you for the suggestion, will help me in future cases, also I've edited my initial request with a solution much more easier and understandable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read from console to a variable, if it is `x` break the loop otherwise set it to your array:

```
for (int i= 0; i<array.Length; i++)
{ 
    string input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    if (input == "x" || input == "X") break;
    else array[i] = input;
    multiply *= Convert.ToDouble(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your current approach does not yield the desired result because `a` is never set inside of the loop; you have to re-set `a` accordingly inside of the loop.