# Console app only terminates when holding key down while running batch script

Tags: c#, batch-file, console-application

I am trying to create a C# console application that repeatedly runs a .bat file and saves the output into a variable to be modified later. The script is meant to get open TCP connections on a connected device using `adb.exe`.

I want the application to quit when the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed (once). To accomplish this I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891612/8628766) and implemented it like so:

***Program.cs***

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press escape to quit");
    do
    {
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine("Application is running");
            RunBatch();
        }
    } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    Console.WriteLine("While loop was exited");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void RunBatch()
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Dev\Batch\GetTcpConnections.bat";
    p.Start();

    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    p.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

***GetTcpConnections.bat***

```
@echo off
echo %time%
adb.exe shell cat /proc/net/tcp
timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul
```

The expected result would be, that the console application exits the loop and prints `While loop was exited` directly upon pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>. It works like this when I comment `RunBatch()` and un-comment `Console.WriteLine("Application is running"`. However, when I am running the batch script, I need to hold down <kbd>Esc</kbd> for about a second or two before the program exits the while loop, instead of being instantaneous.

At first I thought that the input may be blocked by `timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul` in the batch script, but removing this line made no difference. Am I missing something else here that could block inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should solve your problem. Note that I have moved the timeout away from the batch file and placed it within the `while` loop.

***Program.cs***

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press escape to quit");

    do
    {
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            RunBatch();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

    Console.WriteLine("While loop has exited");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void RunBatch()
{
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            FileName = @"C:\Dev\Batch\GetTcpConnections.bat"
        }
    };

    process.Start();
    Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}
```

***GetTcpConnections.bat***

```
@echo off
echo %time%
adb.exe shell cat /proc/net/tcp
```

Comment: Works like a charm! The "odd" thing is that this doesn't work without the `Thread.Sleep(1000);` (as I had tried that before). But that is probably due to the fact as Martin explains in his answer that "adb.exe" is then constantly in control, and the console app has "too small a window" to capture the escape key between runs. Obviously it waits out the full `Thread.Sleep` before exiting. But that is to be expected. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as your consoleapp starts `adb.exe`, it looses the focus. When an applicaties does not have the focus, it does not receive any keyboard input, because the keyboard input goes to another focused application.

You can reclaim the focus by selecting the consoleapp with your mouse, while  `adb.exe` is running, and than press `ESC`. But I guess that is not what you want.

I see serveral "solutions":

- You could find a way to make your consoleapp always the top-level applicatie.
- Make it a Desktop / Winform-application which has a bug "QUIT"-button.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Then when "adb.exe" finishes focus goes back to the console app giving a window for "delete" to be registred.  I tried as your suggested to click on the console app to gain focus, and then press escape. This however still doesn't register. I'll look into making it always top-level application, winform application would indeed work. But gonna try to get it working as a console app first. thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I did not test it, but I can imagine that even if your consoleapp has the focus, the console things that `GetTcpConnections.bat` is the curently running application which receives the keystrokes. And if `adb.exe` is also running inside the console window, that application will receive the keystrokes.