# Reset clock when enter key is pressed

Tags: c#

I have created a 24 hour clock and I want to be able to reset it to 00:00:00 when the enter key is pressed. The clock itself functions fine but I am unable to include the reset functionality properly

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Clock _clock = new Clock();
        ConsoleKeyInfo _key = Console.ReadKey();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_clock.Time);
            _clock.Tick();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            if (_key.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                _clock.Reset();
            }
     }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app

Comment: Thanks. I had some problems with implementation, but I have solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you only read the current keypress once- at the very beginning of your program. `Console.Readkey()` will wait for you to press a key, then return the key you pressed (which then gets stored in `_key`). Because you never read another keypress inside the loop, `_key` will never change.

Of course, you can't simply call `Console.ReadKey()` inside the loop or the program will pause and wait for you to press a key during every iteration, so you'll want to follow the [advice Aybe linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app) in his comment.

Comment: Thanks. I had some problems with implementation, but I have solved it