# C# enter mathematical problem and solve it when user enter "="

Tags: c#

I have some test. I need to do and I just can't understand how to do it.

We are asked to make a program that will take the user input (numbers and operators) and will end to take inputs if the user enters "=", then it will solve it.

Example:
user input - 10+10+10+10= (will stop cuz he enterd = and calculate)
will be like that 10+10+10+10=40

```
int sum;
int num;
char x;
string op;
Console.WriteLine("lets start sum some numbers!");
Console.WriteLine("enter number and than + press = to end and sum all the numbers");

do
{
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        op = Console.ReadLine();
    }
} while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.OemPlus);
```

So this is what I thought to start with but I'm not sure if its the right way.
I managed to find the key available so I think that will check whether or not the user pressed the = key.

It needs to check for every char the user write but the all input in my opinion need to be string.

Anywhay thanks for helpers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listen for key press in .NET console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app)

Comment: I'd just go with `while ((op = Console.ReadLine()) != "=") { }` for  the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need something like this:

```
string s = "";

while(true)
{
 char c = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

 if(c == '=')
  break;

 s += c;
}

// here comes the part where you parse and evaluate the formula in s and print the result
```

Answer (score 0):

try this concept

```
char x = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
if(x != '='){

sum = sum + num;

}else{
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```