# Making a task run while also waiting for a key to be pressed

Tags: c#, console-application

Okay so i'm posting this again because someone thought I asked a question that already has the answer...
This link ([Listen for key press in .NET console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app)) did not help me because I can't use the " while (! Console.KeyAvailable)" I need to know the value of the key.

I have a problem with a 'game' I'm trying to build on a console. So basically I am waiting for a key (A, S, D or W) to be pressed so I can move my character, but with that I can't use Console.ReadKey(true) because it freezes everything and I can't lets say update the enemies' location. Can you help me out a little? Here is part of my code:

```
ConsoleKey key;
            do
            {
                key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

                //Let enemies move on their own here!

                map[player.Position.y, player.Position.x] = ' ';
                CalculateMap(true);
                if (player.IsMoveable(key, mapSize))
                {
                    player.Move(key);
                }

                map[player.Position.y, player.Position.x] = player.icon;
                CalculateMap(false);

                Thread.Sleep(8);
            } while (key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listen for key press in .NET console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app)

Comment: @melancia IT does not I said it in the post...

Comment: `Task.Run(() => CalculateMap(true));`?? At the beginning of your `do`

Comment: I need the code ```key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;``` to run on a different thread (I think) so it can record the action, but I also need to use its value. Im not sure how threads work I haven't used them. Can you suggest an example :/?

Comment: @WhiteWolfDev There are plenty of them out there, just do a search.

Comment: This question has already [been closed once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65737987/making-a-task-run-while-also-waiting-for-a-key-to-be-pressed). You've made no further attempt apart from saying that the duplicate isn't useful...

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks I will be back tomorrow if I haven't fount a solution

Comment: @Liam OP clarified that the duplicate is not an answer to their question. The wording is not great but I don't think this question should be closed. It's easily answerable and reflects at least a little effort on OP's part- they likely just don't know what to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to start your game loop in a new thread, and check a static variable containing the pressed key somewhere inside the game loop.

Static variables in C# are not thread static by default: their value is the same regardless of the thread that accesses them.

So you should be able to do something like the following:

```
class MyGame {

    static ConsoleKeyInfo THE_PRESSED_KEY;

    public static void main() {
        Task.Run( () => UpdateAndDrawTheGame() );

        do {
            THE_PRESSED_KEY = Console.ReadKey();
        } while (THE_PRESSED_KEY.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

    }

    public static void UpdateAndDrawTheGame() {

        while (THE_PRSSED_KEY == null) ; // Wait for the first key read

        while (THE_PRESSED_KEY.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape) {

            // Update the enemies, scenery, HUD etc.

            // Move the character if THE_PRESSED_KEY is 'A'
            // Move the character differently if THE_PRESSED_KEY is 'S'
            // etc.

            // Redraw the game with the updates
        }
    }
}
```

Note that accessing static variables across threads can lead to some wonky behavior, because sometimes a thread reading the variable tries to do so while another thread is writing it. You should research sharing variables between threads for ways to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.KeyAvailable` can still be used here, just check that a key is available before trying to read it. If it is not, `Console.ReadKey` will not be called and will not block the thread:

```
    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
    }
```