# Listen for key press .NET console app does not stop running application

Tags: c#, .net, loops

I have been researching in how to stop a console application when pressing esc (or any key really.

I ran into this solution
[Listen for key press in .NET console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app)

Now, I was trying to apply it to my case:
I should stop my console app, which is a loop, when I press any key.

Coming from the solution provided in the topic above, I added my own part as follows:

```
  Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to stop");
    do {
        while (! Console.KeyAvailable) {
            
            foreach (var station in WeatherStations.station)
            {
                var stationAirParams = station.value?.FirstOrDefault();

                Console.WriteLine(
                    station.name + " " + (stationAirParams == null 
                        ? "" 
                        : stationAirParams.value)
                );
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }       
    } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
```

That said... why isn't the loop stopping?

Comment: it will keep enumerating stations and wait a tenth of a second every time. does it not exit even when all stations are processed?

Comment: Exactly, it enumerates the stations like you said and it stops when all of them have been processed. The problem is that when I press esc or any key, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach uses polling in a single thread, and it is not event driven.
The inner loop won't stop on key press. It will simply finish its work before the code checks for key press for the first time in the outer loops.

Move an abort condition like the following

```
 if(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
 {
     break;
 }
```

to the innermost loop.

There is another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891596/1132334) which shows how to spawn a background thread to do the work whilst waiting for a keypress to exit on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any suggestion on how I can stop the look by pressing any key (not just ESC)

Comment: check for `KeyAvailable` only, remove the second part of the condition