# C# Console application: Trap key press event without waiting for a key to be pressed

Tags: c#, events, console, keypress

I am writing a console application using C#. I am unable to find a way to trap a key down (without having to wait for a key press in a loop). I want my program to run something without waiting for key press. However when any key is pressed, the event should be detected for some action

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This was already answered here:
[Listen for key press in .NET console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app)

You can use do while while checking Console.KeyAvailable or stop application to wait for read key but do work in background thread.

Answer (score 1):

As Ernestas mentioned above Console.KeyAvailable is likely your best bet. To implement it I would do something like this:

```
bool keyPressed = false;
while(!keyPressed)
{
  if(Console.KeyAvailable)
    keyPressed = true;
  //DO STUFF WHILE WAITING FOR KEYPRESS
}
else
{
  //DO STUFF YOU WANTED TO DO AFTER KEYPRESS
}
```