# Loop that runs until certain key is pressed - C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to make a loop that runs until a certain key is pressed without breaking. I'm making a C# console app with .NET 6.0.

What I am aiming for is a loop that continuously until a certain key is pressed. This first example is what I've been using. This loop listens for the key 'L' to be pressed while the key pressed isn't 'B'. However, if a different key is pressed, say 'm', the loop becomes unresponsive and does not do anything when key 'L' or 'B' is pressed afterwards

Example 1 ([source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoJI8vMFniI))

```
 do {
       if (key == ConsoleKey.L)
       {
          // Do stuff
       }
 } while (key != ConsoleKey.B);

 // Do stuff after the 'B' key is pressed
```

In this second example I tried, the loop is unresponsive to any form of input.

Example 2 ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app))

```
while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.L))   
{
    if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.N) 
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

// Do stuff when the key 'L' is pressed
```

Is there a fairly simple fix in which I can have a loop which runs until a certain key is pressed, without breaking when a different key is pressed?

Comment: you're checking the key twice within every iteration. So on the `while` you're calling `ReadKey`, and in the following if-statement you call that function again, which would be a second key-stroke.

Comment: In your first example - you don't read 'key' value inside the do..while loop. If the value of 'key' is not 'B' on entry to the loop, it will be an infinite loop. If I add "key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;" before the if statement, then your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the solutions in static functions to be more clear.

You could use two different solutions, either use a switch statement that check the key pressed:

```
static void Solution1()
{
    while (!(Console.KeyAvailable))
    {
        switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.L: Console.WriteLine("L pressed"); break;
            case ConsoleKey.N: Console.WriteLine("N pressed"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Or do a while loop that breaks if your key is pressed, without use a break statement (you can name "conK" variable what you want) :

```
static void Solution2()
{
    ConsoleKey conK = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable && conK != ConsoleKey.L)
    {
        if (conK == ConsoleKey.N) Console.WriteLine("N pressed.");  // Do stuff if N is pressed
        conK = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Loop broke, L pressed."); // Do stuff after L is pressed and loop broke
}
```

I tested both before posting, but I'm sure that the second solution is what you're looking for.