# (C#) How to know if a key is held down in .NET Console Application

Tags: c#, console, keyboard, console-application

I want to know, if a key is held down by the user. I know how to do that in WinForms, but no clue in Console App. I don't want to download any C++ libraries or anything. Just want to know if you can do that using the `System` namespace.

So, as you know, `Console.ReadKey()` stops the application until a key is pressed. I tried doing `Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape` in an `if` statement (of course I also used `else` after that to change things back to `false`). It worked at first glance, but there is an obvious lag between key press and the reaction.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a "while" statement.
For example:

```
while (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
}
```

Comment: Here's a good resource for beginners https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_while_loop.php Thanks for the upvote it means a lot!